# OpenVZ: Many subdomains on a single IP for the VMs

Tags: networking, openvz

Can I Use many sub domains that get assigned to OpenVZ containers with a single ip for a dedicated server?

To elaborate further: I have one IP and one domain. I want to have two OpenVZ containers and do something like this:

`Container1: 1.domain.com`

`Container2: 2.domain.com`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses and domain names don't really have anything to do with each other.

To attempt to answer your question(s) It really depends on the setup of the containers though. If you have them setup so that they're behind a NAT and then create firewall rules to access the systems through a firewall to expose various ports and services (such as Apache, etc.) on these containers then you can get by with 1 IP and essentially stack the domainnames on top of this IP.

If you're intending to run more complicated things such as Samba, then these will require dedicated IP addresses of their own.

Comment: I intend to run nginx in both of them, along with a custom server application. at the moment I have a setup where the custom server listens to a subdomain (on ports 7171 & 7172) and nginx to the normal domain, but I wish to expand the server, this is why I ask. I planned on running the containers bridged, do you recommend this?

Comment: @Dominique - This is exactly what I do. I "stack" many domains on top of a single IP and use nginx/apache to virtualhost them. I can then reverse proxy to the various openvz internal hosts port@host. I've used both Apache and Nginx. Nginx is easier, I've been contemplating using something even lighter such as HAProxy or Pound as well. The drawback to this architecture is that it's difficult to diagnose issues, esp. w/ the backend apps.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using virtual hosts because I want to keep them separate. I wanted to try to avoid using a single MySQL process and a single nginx(as inefficient as that sounds) to keep things simple without having to configure the servers to use the single database. Looks like I will have to do that, unless you have any other recommendation?

Comment: There isn't a way to do "stacking" except the manner I've described.

Comment: Can I run mysql and nginx on the openvz kernel while hosting VMs? I wont have any problems? I still need the containers for the other server because they dont support running side-by-side.

Comment: @Dominique - yes it's a regular machine otherwise. I typically run ntpd on mine rather than fill up all the slices with their own.